# Fit image to div and vertical align

Tags: css

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QVCHT/20/)**

I have a div in a fluid layout, I need to keep the aspect ratio 1:1. Inside this `di`v I sometimes have text, sometimes an image, sometimes both.

The text needs to be vertically aligned.

The image needs to be vertically aligned and fit inside the div and maintain it's own aspect ratio.

I have achieved most of the above, my only issue is I cannot get the image to vertically align and not exceed the size of the `div` at the same time.

This maintains 1:1 ratio of the `div`:

```css
#upload-drop{
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    position: relative; 
}

#upload-drop:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;
}

#upload-drop >div{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

This vertically aligns content:

```css
.valign-center{
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.valign-center:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: -0.25em;
}
.valign-center-content{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Finally, this keeps an image to it's aspect ratio and fit inside a parent div:

```css
#upload-img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}    
img{  
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

If I remove width and height on `#upload-img` everything vertically aligns, but portrait images will now no longer fit to the `div`.

How can I get them to play nice together?

Answer (score 0):

With these changes, your examples work at fluid widths. I'm uncertain how they would react to extreme portrait images.

Without the change to 80% width, the images would remain centered, but escape the bounds of the parent element.

```
#upload-img{
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}    
img{  
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    max-width: 80%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please add below styles in the image tag.

```
style="width:100%;height:100%"
```

check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nvLua2kb/)

Comment: Your suggestions prevent the div having 1:1 width & height.

Comment: @panthro  i have modified the answer. can you please try

Comment: You can add this style inline or change the css **img** class 'img{  
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
'